# Firefox not playing video recorded in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, web-mediarecorder

I have a video that was recorded in Chrome using this react plugin: [rico345100/react-multimedia-capture](https://github.com/rico345100/react-multimedia-capture).  This video is uploaded to a server.

The video is playing fine in Chrome.  However, the same video does not open in Firefox.  Conversely, a video recorded in Firefox plays fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
                      |  Works in Firefox |  Works in Chrome |
----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
  Recorded in Firefox |         Y         |         Y        |
----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
   Recorded in Chrome |         N         |         Y        |
```

How can we address this issue?

Comment: check which codec Chrome recording uses, check which codec Firefox recording uses, make Chrome use Firefox's codec.

Comment: This question is more suitable to [su], as it pertains to how to use software, not how to build it.

Comment: I am using this plugin
https://github.com/rico345100/react-multimedia-capture/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: @jpaugh I would say it's debatable.  This is more than likely a supported codec issue.  If the video is being served with an unsupported codec, there would need to be a change in the way that content is served which, to me, is a "build" problem.

Comment: @zero298 Perhaps. At the very least, it is unanswerable, in its current state. The OP may need help from SU to discover whether it is indeed a codec issue.

Comment: @jpaugh Yes, I don't think there is not enough information here to be able to answer this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Chrome is (probably encoding the recording as `h246` despite the library that you are using asking it to encode it as `vp8`.  You can see in the library that is asking specifically checking for `vp8` support in this line here:

[react-multimedia-capture, line 101](https://github.com/rico345100/react-multimedia-capture/blob/5c6d8d3a535ec29b2595a0686326eca2c75b1c29/src/index.js#L101)

> ```
> let types = ['video/webm;codecs=vp8', 'video/webm', ''];
> ```

The library also asks the user agent to encode for `video/webm` in this line here:

[react-multimedia-capture, line 177](https://github.com/rico345100/react-multimedia-capture/blob/5c6d8d3a535ec29b2595a0686326eca2c75b1c29/src/index.js#L177)

> ```
> let blob = new Blob(this.mediaChunk, { type: 'video/webm' });
> ```

However, it seems that the user agent is free to encode using whatever codec it would like whenever it creates the `Blob`.

I created a toy project to mimic what the library is doing and trying to dictate the codec when creating the `Blob` doesn't seem to have an effect.  Here are the `ffprobe` outputs of each saved file for each user agent:

### Chrome

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'recording.chrome.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
```

### Firefox

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'recording.firefox.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : QTmuxingAppLibWebM-0.0.1
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.001000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
```

Considering this, your best course of action is to not rely on your browser to encode the recording in a format that can be played by all browsers.  You can either re-encode your videos to a format that is usable by a broader range of user agents, or have your users upload their videos to your server where you can re-encode for them and then conditionally serve the content using `<source>` tags.

You should also read this MDN article about supported file types: [Media formats for HTML audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

Comment: Crazy. Why Google would ignore something that should be configurable via the API is beyond me. As the OP, and I, are finding, this results in vids that other browsers (or at least FF) can't play.